# how to set a bit as a table in c

Tags: c, long-integer, bit

I'm doing an encryption algorithm, DES (Data Encryption Standard). A stretch of the problem:
"Example: Let K be the hexadecimal key K = 133457799BBCDFF1. This gives us
as the binary key (setting 1 = 0001, 3 = 0011, etc., and grouping together every
eight bits, of which the last one in each group will be unused):
K = 00010011 00110100 01010111 01111001 10011011 10111100 11011111
11110001. The 64-bit key is permuted according to the following table, PC-1. Since the first
entry in the table is "57", this means that the 57th bit of the original key K
becomes the first bit of the permuted key K+. The 49th bit of the original key
becomes the second bit of the permuted key. The 4th bit of the original key is the
last bit of the permuted key. Note only 56 bits of the original key appear in the
permuted key." The link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7320170/DES_Illustrated.pdf

I need to set a bit vector as follows. Each position of the bit vector is to be placed in the new.

```
long k = 0x133457799BBCDFF1L;

int pc1[56] = {(57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,
               1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18,
               10, 2, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27,
               19, 11, 3, 60, 52, 44, 36,
               63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15,
               7, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22,
               14, 6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29,
               21, 13, 5, 28, 20, 12, 4)};

//K = 00010011 00110100 01010111 01111001 10011011 10111100 11011111
//should be
//kplus = 1111000 0110011 0010101 0101111 0101010 1011001 1001111 0001111
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might not be aware, but this question is far away from ideal format for this community. Please read up on how to write good questions, otherwise you will end up with many downvotes and without an answer.
What is exactly your questions? Where are you stuck? Please give more description  and show what have you done so far.  I don't really understand what want to do.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? Is it making a function to get `kplus` from 'K'? Tell us exactly and unambiguously what it is you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: You don't want those parens ( ) in your initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that should help:

- The bit-shift operators `<<` (shift left) and `>>` (shift right) can help you build a bit mask.
- The expression `1 << n` will produce a value that has bit *n* set to 1
- Using the `|` (Boolean "or") operator will allow you to set individual bits of a value.  So:

  ```
  mask = (long) 1 << n;
  k = k | mask;
  ```

  will set bit *n* of k.

Updating to expand on this answer, now that you've updated the question:

So your goal is to take the long int K and permute the bits according to how they're listed in  `pc1`:

- The value in `pc1[0]` is 57, which means that bit #57 in K should be the value of bit #0 in K'.
- The value in `pc1[1]` is 49, which means that bit #49 in K should be the value of bit #1 in K'.
- The value in `pc1[2]` is 41, which means that bit #41 in K should be the value of bit #2 in K'.
- etc.

What you need to do, then, could be expressed in pseudocode like this:

```
for each element 'n' in pc1:
    let b = pc1[n]
    use a bit mask to filter out bit #b in k
    create a new bit mask, with bit #n set to the above value
    use Boolean "or" with this bit mask to set bit #n in your target value
```

You should have all the tools you need to write that now, but if there's part of it that's still unclear I'm happy to expand on it more.